# How Do I Use The Value of a Lookup Column in a 2013 Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a list used for scheduling appointments. Each item in the list is an appointment date/time. **Column A** is a *Number* column indicating the total number of appointment slots, **Column B** is a calculated *Lookup* column that results in the total number of appointments that have been scheduled for that time. Finally, there's a **Status** column indicating whether or not the date/time is "Active" or "Full." A list item is "Active" when there are appointment slots available, and "Full" when there are none. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

Let's say there are 8 appointment slots available (**Column A**) on 10/12 at 9am and 3 appointments have been scheduled (**Column B**). I need a way to compare the value in **Column B** (3) to the value in **Column A** (8) and automatically set the **Status** of the item to "Full" once **Column B** reaches the limit set in **Column A**.

Can anyone share a way to get the value of the Lookup column (**Column B**) so that I can compare it to the value in **Column A** in a 2013 Workflow and set the **Status** accordingly?

I have tried having my current 2013 Workflow set a separate text field to the current item's **Column B** value to no avail. The text field is never set to the value in **Column B**.

Everything we have is on-prem, we don't have O365, so I don't have any of the newer functionality such as Microsoft Flows.

Thank you for any/all help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, I think you just need to add **If condition** to compare the value of `Column A` with the value of `column B` (Lookup field) in the current list items.

**Simply,**

- Add IF condition.
- In `If condition`, Set the first value to column A.
- Set the second value of the lookup column (Column B) as shown below.

[image]

**Finally**, use the "`Set Field in Current Item`" to set the status value if the condition is correct!

[image]

**Check also,** [Using Lookup Field in SharePoint Workflow](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mohamed! I've actually reviewed that blog post of yours multiple times.  
  
I'll try to clarify. **Column B** is a Lookup field which is referencing the "Title" field of another list and counting the related items in that list. As a result, **Column B** is the **total number of appointments scheduled** for a date/time.  
  
When I try to have the workflow compare **Column B** to **Column A** (a number field manually set to the number of appointment slots available), it doesn't work as it never actually gets the value from **Column B**.